# What is the best way to convert a 2D string vector to a 2D int vector c++?

Tags: c++

I am reading a matrix from a file, I am reading it into a string vector so I can preserve the leading 0s in the file. Now I want to apply some mathematical operations on the vector and so I want to copy it into a 2D int vector. I am new to using vectors and I saw there was a couple of examples for 1D vectors, but I am confused with 2D vectors.

```
std::vector< std::vector<string> > data;
std::vector< std::vector<int> > res;
std::ifstream f("input.txt", ios::binary);
std::string line;

while(std::getline(f,line))
{
  std::vector<string> line_data;
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  std::string value;
  while(iss >> value)
    {   
        line_data.push_back(value);
}
  data.push_back(line_data);
}
```

My code above read the file line by line as a string and wrote it to the 2D string vector named data. My goal is to copy 2D data vector to the 2D res vector, how do I proceed with that ?

input.txt is a square boolean matrix.
for instance

```
0101
1010
1100
0001
```

edit:

As recommended I tried using the transform function and this is where I got to :

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
{   std::vector<int> temp_data;

    std::transform(data[i].begin(), data[i].end(),
            std::back_inserter(temp_data),
            [](const auto& element) {   return std::stoi(element); });
    res.push_back(temp_data);
}
```

but I am getting an invalid use of auto error here, and I am not even sure this is right for 2D vectors.

Comment: Not having seen your input data, I might be off but I would say, instead of reading tokens of string from `iss`, read numbers. `int value; while  (iss >> value)  { ... }`

Comment: i tried this but i loose the leading 0s while reading the file.

Comment: Are you hoping to translate each of those tokens into four numbers?

Comment: Yes so i can access the vector as res[0][0] res[0][1] etc

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a lambda that calls [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Here's an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vs = {"123", "456", "789"};
    std::vector<int> vi;
    std::transform(vs.begin(), vs.end(),
        std:back_inserter(vi),
        [](const auto& element) { return std::stoi(element); });
// 'vi' now contains the integers 123, 456, 789
}
```

Comment: I saw this example, but I dont understand how to use it for a 2D vector.

Comment: @Ashwin Ramesh the example I posted takes care of one dimension, I left the other one out as an exercise for the reader, but it's trivial; just wrap a `for` loop around it or, another `transform`.

Comment: @ Jesper Juhl, I made an edit as to what you suggested, could you please review the code ?

Comment: I'm getting an invalid use of 'auto'

Comment: @Ashwin Ramesh make sure you compile as C++14

Comment: I'm compiling on dev c++  gcc 4.9.2 and I enabled -std= ISO c++11